# Error in Joomla's login module. Making logout in reset password link

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, module

Good morning guys, I'm having a boring error in the Joomla login module. The same is generating the link to reset the password with a logout, so the user is not able to reset the password because it is being sent directly to the home page

Follows the HTML of the login form that Joomla is generating

```
<form action="http://mydomain.com.br/pt-br/component/k2/conteudo/teste-login" method="post" id="login-form" class="form-inline">
        <div class="userdata">
        <div id="form-login-username" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-user hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="Nome de Usuário"></span>
                            <label for="modlgn-username" class="element-invisible">Nome de Usuário</label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="Nome de Usuário">
                    </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form-login-password" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-lock hasTooltip" title="" data-original-title="Senha">
                            </span>
                                <label for="modlgn-passwd" class="element-invisible">Senha                          </label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="Senha">
                    </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
                        <div id="form-login-remember" class="control-group checkbox">
            <label for="modlgn-remember" class="control-label">Lembrar-me</label> <input id="modlgn-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes">
        </div>
                <div id="form-login-submit" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" tabindex="0" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
                    <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li>
                    <a href="/pt-br/logout?view=remind">
                    Esqueceu seu usuário?</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/pt-br/logout?view=reset">
                    Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users">
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="aHR0cDovL2ZiYjQxMDAuZnVuZGFjYW9iYi5vcmcuYnIvcHQtYnIvY29tcG9uZW50L2syL2NvbnRldWRvL3Rlc3RlLWxvZ2lu">
        <input type="hidden" name="977f8d1259061641a0377eecaa321eeb" value="1"> </div>
    </form>
```

See that the link being generated is **/pt-br/logout?view=reset** the correct one should be only **/pt-br/?view=reset** without the logout part

It's a default Joomla module so it was not something I created I'm just calling as it is spoken in forums.

I already checked if it is some JS that is changing the code then it is not either.

I looked at the Joomla com_user and it looks all normal

Any idea what might be changing this link?